# importxml not working gives error for all queries

Tags: google-sheets

I keep getting formula parser error for-every code I try.

```
=importXML("http://purplle.com/trending","//*[@id="mason-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div")")"

=importXML("http://www.amazon.in/gp/goldbox/","//*[@id="shove_01"]/div[2]/ul")
```

I have tried with many others but each time same error.

Comment: "mason-container" and "shove_01" - are these named ranges?

Comment: yes thts those are present

Answer (score 0):

If you are using named ranges as ID you should put **&** in order to combine and turn it to string

```
=importXML("http://www.amazon.in/gp/goldbox/","//*[@id="&NamedRange&"]/div[2]/ul")
```

Also your first formula has double closing brackets, it should be

```
=importXML("http://purplle.com/trending","//*[@id="&NamedRange&"]/div[2]/div/div/div")
```

You can not have a "-" in a name of the range.